# How to initialize kendo ui scheduler data model on create new

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Kendo UI v2015.2.805

kendoScheduler

I implemented a event calendar using kendoScheduler and it is working fine except I cannot initialize the data model when a new event is being created.

I am using a custom template for the scheduler editor. Here is a simplified snippet:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="schedulerTemplate">
    <div >Created by #= xCreatedBy #</div>
</script>
```

When editing an existing event the field xCreatedBy is populated from the database with the name of the person that created it.

```
Created By John Smith
```

To add a new task I double click a date on the calendar and the editor opens, but xCreatedBy is null so it displays:

```
Created By null
```

In the data source I define the data model and provide default values, like in this simplified example:

```
$("#task_calendar").kendoScheduler({
    dataSource: {
    ...CRUD operations....
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "taskId",
            fields: {
                xCreatedBy: { from: "xCreatedBy", defaultValue: "Your_Name" }              }
        }
    }
});
```

I expected xCreatedBy to equal "Your_Name" but it is null.

How can I initialize the model when a new event is created (that is, not queried from the database)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the described behavior and it worked correctly at my side. Here is my test [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@zdravkov/ONaPoSUR).

Comment: Your example works so that is the answer, but there must be something else going on with my setup. Accepted.